# Retorfit2 built in suspend is not recognized

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 to do my api calls and I am having difficulty figuring out what is going on. My IDE right no says that it can not resolve suspend, Invalid method declaration, and unexpected token. I followed what the

This is what is in my Gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:0.10.8"

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.0'
```

Interface :

```
@POST("login")
suspend fun login(@Body loginRequest : LoginRequest): LoggedInUser;
```

Not sure what is going on and not sure if I actually doing what I want right. I want to call the login endpoint but treat it as a sync operation so the user does not proceed to the login page with out the request completing.

Comment: A good start is to use the correct syntax for Kotlin function parameters. Replace `LoginRequest loginRequest` with `loginRequest: LoginRequest`.

Comment: You do not declare a retrofit function like that I followed the docs for the non suspend function for post. No matter how I do it suspend still can not be resolved @POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);

Comment: Is your retrofit interface in a Kotlin file (with .kt file extension)?